# Json serialize error via RecyclableMemoryStream

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I use code like this to replace default json serialize method:

```cs
private readonly static RecyclableMemoryStreamManager _recyclableMemoryStreamManager = 
    new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager(blockSize: 128 * 1024, largeBufferMultiple: 1024 * 1024, maximumBufferSize: 128 * 1024 * 1024);

private ByteArrayContent Serialize(object content, JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings, Encoding encoding, string mediaType)
{
    var jsonSerializer = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings);
    using (var memoryStream = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream())
    {
        using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, encoding, 1024, true))
        {
            using (var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter) { CloseOutput = false })
            {
                jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, content);
                jsonTextWriter.Flush();
                var arraySegment = new ArraySegment<byte>(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
                var resContent = new ByteArrayContent(arraySegment.Array, arraySegment.Offset, arraySegment.Count);
                resContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mediaType);
                return resContent;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But sometimes, http response json with sytanx error:

```json
{
  "code": 0,
  "msg": null,
  "data": [
    // ....
  ]
}
')","foo":"","bar":"baz","flag":0,')","foo":"","bar":"baz","flag":0,
')","foo":"","bar":"baz","flag":0,')","foo":"","bar":"baz","flag":0,
```

How to fix this?

I think it maybe reuse buffer error,

Maybe can change the values of `RecyclableMemoryStreamManager` ?

```cs
_recyclableMemoryStreamManager.AggressiveBufferReturn = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

The buffer from `GetBuffer()` is only well-defined *for the lifetime of the stream*; you dispose the stream when the method exits the `using` block for `memoryStream`, which means those buffers are now up for grabs for re-use.

You may wish to use `StreamContent` instead; this accepts a `Stream` of the payload, and disposes it when sent: I'd use *that*; that would give you the exact semantics you want here. Note: don't dispose `memoryStream` yourself - remove that `using` (perhaps adding a `catch` block that does `memoryStream?.Dispose(); throw;`).

Note also that `GetBuffer()` is *not* necessarily the optimal API for `RecyclableMemoryStream`, since it may use multiple discontiguous buffers internally; there should be a `ReadOnlySequence<byte> GetReadOnlySequence()`  API which allows that usage - however, this still has the same lifetime limitations impacting buffer re-use, so: it wouldn't change anything here.

---

Untested, but for consideration:

```
private HttpContent Serialize(object content, JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings, Encoding encoding, string mediaType)
{
    var jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings);
    var memoryStream = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
    try
    {
        using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, encoding, 1024, true))
        {
            using var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter) { CloseOutput = false };
            jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, content);
            jsonTextWriter.Flush();
        }
        memoryStream.Position = 0; // rewind
        var resContent = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
        resContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mediaType);
        return resContent;
    }
    catch
    {
        memoryStream?.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

---

However, I would *expect* it would be better to serialize directly to the output via the inbuilt JSON media encoder, rather than using an intermediate buffer.